# Yii2 Call to a member function load() on a non-object

Tags: post, yii2, load

I have standard code in controller for User class

```
public function actionEdit($username)
    {
...
        $model = User::findByUsername($username);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
```

And if I edit user I get error

```
Call to a member function load() on a non-object
```

which is pointing at `$model->load`

Why is that ?

**UPDATE**

var_dump on $model shows NULL
which is strange

because I have the same function used in view action and it works perfectly

```
public function actionView($username){
    $model = User::findByUsername($username);
   if($model){
```

**UPDATE2**
I've made some changes now the code is like this, no errors
but the logic goes that there is no load and save, cause if goes to else section and edit is loaded again not view.

```
$model = User::findByUsername($username);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'username' => $model->username]);
        } else {
return $this->render('edit', [
                'model' => $model,
}
```

Comment: If `$model` validation returns false, you need to check if there is any error by `var_dump($model->errors);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var_dump($model);
```

To see what exacly `$model` is. Propably it's not a model, check what's result of function `findByUsername()`

Comment: NULL - why ? Here is findByUsername function in User model

    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username]);
    }

Comment: Propably because it did'nt find it in DB. If it's not present, `findOne()` will return NULL - exacly like in documentation.

Comment: And what is `$username` in `actionView()` and in `actionEdit()`? Dump it please.

Comment: I see the problem is here
view = string(6) "test28"
edit = string(4) "root"
I deleted some code which was causing that. and now there are no errors but load is not working

Comment: But that's not problem which u were asking. Main problem is solved.

Comment: Or try to debug it first.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your function is check and find one, like

```
protected function findByUsername($username)
{
    if (($model = User::find()->where(['username' => $username])->one()) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('not found.');
    }
}
```